# Using '!' here is deprecated and will be removed in a future release - swift 4.2

Tags: ios, option-type, compiler-warnings, sdwebimage, swift4.2

Compiler throwing following warning when setting image in a cell using SDWebimage in Swift 4.2.

**Swift Compiler warning :**

> **Using '!' here is deprecated and will be removed in a future release**

```
let url = NSURL(string: (str_url) as String)

cell.img!.sd_setImage(with: url as URL!, completed: block_image) //--- WARNING ON THIS LINE AT URL!
```

Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code : `cell. img!.sd_setImage(with: url! as URL, completed: block_image)`

Suggestion: use `URL` instead of `NSURL`

```
            let url = URL(string: "" ) //use url String
            cell.img!.sd_setImage(with: url, completed: block_image)
```

Comment: plz add `Using '!' here is deprecated and will be removed in a future release` related document

Comment: @Anbu.karthik I have found this documents plz review it bro : https://swift.org/blog/iuo/ and https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#swift-42  in this doc Swift 4.2 Section > SE-0054.

Comment: @imgroot Plz approve answer if you find it correct and I will explain it to you. try with this doc you will get a better idea : https://swift.org/blog/iuo/

Comment: if you write x as T!, the compiler will first attempt to type check this as x as T?. Only if that fails, the compiler will attempt to type check it as (x as T?)!, forcing the optional.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if let url = URL(string: str_url) {
    cell.img!.sd_setImage(with: url, completed: block_image)
}
```