# Using '!' here is deprecated and will be removed in a future release

Tags: warnings, ios12, swift4.2

There are two areas of my ViewController that are showing this warning.

```
  geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (data, error) -> Void in
        guard let placeMarks = data as? [CLPlacemark] else { // warning
            return
        }
        let loc: CLPlacemark = placeMarks[0]
        let addressDict : [NSString: NSObject] = loc.addressDictionary as! [NSString: NSObject]
        let addrList = addressDict["FormattedAddressLines"] as! [String]
```

~ and ~

```
 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

    print("Returning Custom label")
    var label = view as! UILabel!// warning
    if label == nil {
        label = UILabel()
    }

    label?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 18)!
    ....
```

How can I fix these?

Comment: So what should it be?

Comment: Not sure what conditional casting is. Can you show me in code example?

Comment: Please have a look at https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TypeCasting.html (specifically the "Downcasting" part) and also you should read about Optionals in the Swift manual ebook by Apple, everything is there. Optionals are an essential part of Swift.

Comment: @Moritz The OP isn't trying to force-unwrap a type, they are trying to cast the variable to an implicitly unwrapped variable

Comment: @Carpsen90 Ah, yes, makes sense, I see it now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52491298/using-here-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-a-future-release-swift-4-2/52491545#52491545

Answer (score 0):

According to the [SE-0054](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md) proposal, which has been implemented as of Swift 4.2, the use of implicitly unwrapped optional values is restricted to:

- property and variable declarations
- initializer declarations
- function and method declarations
- subscript declarations
- parameter declarations
  (with the exception of vararg parameters)

And downcasting with `as!` is not one of them

Comment: So what do i do in thee cases?

Comment: @LizG Just remove the `!` after the type you want to cast to

Comment: I am not near computer atm but i tried that and it gave me more errors

Comment: When you get to a computer, try adding more info on `data` and `view` in the question. One thing for sure is the casting operator should be optional: `a?`

Comment: I updated the question to include some more info on data and view.
In the first part of the question re: data, I removed 'as? [CLPlacemark' in] guard let placeMarks = data as? [CLPlacemark] else } - it took the warning away.  Everything seems ok but can't seem to fix the one with the "view"