# Trying to understand this warning:[UITabBarItem]! Using '!' here is deprecated and will be removed in a future release

Tags: swift

In my code I have this, but this part 
**[UITabBarItem]!** is causing this warning. Now I'm sure it has to do with casting but I can't find a way to stop it from warning about it.

> Using '!' here is deprecated and will be removed in a future release

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for item in self.tabBar.items as [UITabBarItem]! {
        if let image = item.image {
            item.image = image.imageWithColor(tintColor: self.normalTint).withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
        }
    }
}
```

This question is different, and is explained by rmaddy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using '!' here is deprecated and will be removed in a future release - swift 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52491298/using-here-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-a-future-release-swift-4-2)

Comment: Simply remove the `!`. It's pointless. Better yet, remove the whole `as [UITabBarItem]!` since the whole cast is pointless.

Comment: Which in turn generates the Error: Type '[UITabBarItem]?' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'. Just removing the ! generates a different error: '[UITabBarItem]?' is not convertible to '[UITabBarItem]'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?

Comment: I forgot that `items` returns an optional array. Safely unwrap it first. Again, no need for the `!` or the cast. That's not the proper way to safely unwrap an optional.

Comment: Ok, this works. 
for item in self.tabBar.items! {

Comment: That's not safely unwrapping. That's "crash if `items` is nil".

Comment: items is never nil.

Comment: otherwise I have to do this
if items != nil { ... someFunc(items!) ... }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made sure that there would not be a crash by adding a guard:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    guard let items = self.tabBar.items else { return }
    for item in items {
        if let image = item.image {
            item.image = image.imageWithColor(tintColor: self.normalTint).withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
        }
    }
}
```